# Extremely simple flexbox layout, with overflow: hidden -- vertical mis-alignment in Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I'm trying to put two flex items side by side, baseline-aligned (simple enough!), but with some small constraints: (1) `overflow: hidden` on both; (2) some `padding-top` on the second flex item. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner one">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner two">Hello</div>
</div>
```

...and the CSS:

```
.outer { 
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
.inner {
  width: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.one {
  background: red;
}
.two {
  background: yellow;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

While Chrome (v43) gets the layout right (or at least what one could expect), Firefox (v38) breaks it completely: open [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhrb0nmq/5/) in Firefox and you'll see.

**Any workaround for correct vertical alignment?** It's so simple I can't believe both major browsers don't offer the same result.

Comment: Thanks to the poster of a deleted answer for [this article](http://kizu.ru/en/blog/flex-baseline/) -- some great ideas can be found there!

Comment: May be of some use: 
http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: (EDIT:  Sorry, I misread the testcase; it's not this bug after all.)

Comment: @dholbert: is there any workaround?

Comment: Oh actually, I misunderstood the testcase -- this is a different bug I think. (Not sure about workarounds)

Comment: Possible workaround: put the "overflow:hidden" on a wrapper-div inside of each flex item, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/xhrb0nmq/7/

Comment: I filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1179108 on this, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for this is fairly simple.

```
.outer { 
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Note using flex-end for an align property, and not baseline. Baseline is a complicated thing in flexbox as far as i can see. If you want to achieve proper results with baseline you should maybe fancy up that example of yours with some more typography.

About the overflow problem and why it acts like that im not really sure about. Still i hope you can workaround your issue like that.

I advise you on reading this great, so called ["Complete Guide to Flexbox"](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Greetings!